# Javascript summing arrays, using d3.nest()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I had data that looked like this:

```
harvest = [{type: "apple", color: "green", value: 1}, 
           {type: "apple", color: "red", value: 2}, 
           {type: "grape", color: "green", value: 3},
           {type: "grape", color: "red", value: 4 }]
```

I could sum it by various attributes using d3's nest.rollup() function:

```
sum_by = "color";

rollup = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
  return d[sum_by];
}).rollup(function(d) {
  return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
    return g.value;
  });
}).entries(harvest);
```

Giving me this:

```
rollup = [{key: "green", values: 4},
          {key: "red", values: 6}]
```

Which is just what I want.

However the values in my data consist of arrays, all of equal length:

```
harvest = [{type: "apple", color: "green", values: [1,2,3,4]}, 
           {type: "apple", color: "red", values: [5,6,7,8]}, 
           {type: "grape", color: "green", values: [9,10,11,12]},
           {type: "grape", color: "red", values: [13,14,15,16] }]
```

Is it possible to combine these in a similar way? To give for example:

```
rollup = [{key: "green", values: [10,12,14,16]},
          {key: "red", values: [18,20,22,24]}]
```

I feel this is probably possible using a d3 rollup function (but it doesn't necessarily have to be done using d3).

**RESOLUTION**

Thanks to the efforts of @meetamit and @Superboggly I have three solutions:

Version 1 (preferred because it uses `reduce()` just once and `map()` just once):

```
function sumArrays(group) {
  return group.reduce(function(prev, cur, index, arr) {
    return {
      values: prev.values.map(function(d, i) {
        return d + cur.values[i];
      })
    };
  });
}
```

Version 2:

```
function sumArrays(group) {
  return group.map(function(h) {
    return h.values;
  }).reduce(function(prev, cur, index, arr) {
    return prev.map(function(d, i) {
      return d + cur[i];
    });
  });
}
```

Version 3 (for interest because array length can vary):

```
function sumArrays(group) {
  return group.reduce(function(prev, cur, index, arr) {
    return prev.map(function(d, i) {
      return d + cur.values[i];
    });
  }, [0, 0, 0, 0]);
}
```

Called like this:

```
function rollupArrays() {
  return d3.nest().key(function(d) {
    return d[sum_by];
  }).rollup(sumArrays).entries(harvest);
}
```

And converted to CoffeeScript:

```
rollupArrays = ->
  d3.nest().key (d) ->
    d[sum_by]
  .rollup(sumArrays).entries(harvest)

sumArrays = (group) ->
  group.reduce (prev, cur, index, arr) ->
    values: prev.values.map (d,i) ->
      d + cur.values[i]
```

**UPDATE**

This method isn't suitable if the function must run, even with one input row.  See [Part II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713784/summing-arrays-in-javascript-using-d3-nest-part-ii)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution uses `[].reduce()` and `[].map()`:

```
// eg: sumArrays([ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8] ]);// <- outputs [6, 8, 10, 12]
function sumArrays(arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce(
    function(memo, nums, i) {
      if(i == 0)
        return nums.concat();
      else
        return memo.map(
          function(memoNum, i) {
            return memoNum + nums[i];
          }
        );
    },
    [ ]// Start with empty Array for memo
  );
}
```

Both reduce and map are not native in old JS, so best use a module (underscore, or maybe there's a d3 equivalent to `reduce`, but I haven't seen it).

**EDIT**

Using it in your code:

```
sum_by = "color";

rollup = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
  return d[sum_by];
}).rollup(function(d) {
  var arraysToSum = d.map(function(g) { return g.values; });
  return sumArrays(arraysToSum)
}).entries(harvest);
```

Comment: Thanks. This function works, but I haven't yet figured out how to apply it.  Simply doing "return sumArrays(d, function(g) { return g.values;..." doesn't work, giving "memo.map is not a function."  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Great.  Took me a moment to get my head round this but working perfectly now.

Comment: Cool, thanks. But you should probably use @Superboggly's solution, since it's even more compact (still uses the same `reduce()` method).

Comment: OK.  It's good having both these solutions because I can take them to bits and really get into these methods. Thanks!

Comment: meetamit, based on the point about reduce() working without an initial value how do you feel about the version in my edit above?  Based on my testing so far it seems to work.

Comment: It's fine, but it's slightly less compact than @Supperboggly's, because it requires an extra `map()` operation to prepare the values passed into `sumArray`. It's fine either way though.

Comment: meetamit, @Superboggly I have posted a follow up question to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713784/summing-arrays-in-javascript-using-d3-nest-part-ii) and if you were up for having a look that would be extremely welcome!

Answer (score 2):

@meetamit I like your idea of using reduce.

If you want to solve this just using d3 it also has a built in reduce which you can use in conjunction with the nest function:

```
var rollup = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
  return d[sum_by];
}).rollup(function(d) {
    var result = d.reduce(function(prev, cur, index, arr) {
        return prev.values.map(function(d,i) { return d + cur.values[i];});
    });

    return result;
}).entries(harvest);
```

If you want you can play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rS7d8/).

Comment: Actually, this is still using the native `reduce()`, but much more compactly than my version. I hadn't realized that reduce can work without an initial value (in which case it starts from the 2nd element, passing in the 1st val). Cool.

Comment: I'm afraid there's a bug in here.  When I add another row to my data with an existing type or color (e.g. a 3rd row for "apple" like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/derekhill/rFZSH/1/)) I get the message "prev.values is undefined."  Any suggestions?

Comment: @DerekHill, I [modified your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFZSH/2/) to fix this bug, by adding `{ values:... }` (too hard to explain why, you need to think about it). Solution is kinda iffy.

Comment: Ah, yeah! That is not very good for my solution! Basically I am changing the type of prev as it goes - you don't notice when there are only two items to iterate through. meetamit's fix is good! In the interest of providing yet another alternative you can also pass in an initialization value to the reduce method. Check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rS7d8/3/)

Answer (score 1):

This solution makes use of [`d3.rollups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#rollups) and [`d3.transpose`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#transpose), new features of [`d3.array`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array):

```js
var input = [
  { type: "apple", color: "green", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  { type: "apple", color: "red",   values: [5, 6, 7, 8] },
  { type: "grape", color: "green", values: [9, 10, 11, 12] },
  { type: "grape", color: "red",   values: [13, 14, 15, 16] }
];

var rolled_up = d3.rollups(
  input,
  vs => d3.transpose(vs.map(d => d.values)).map(vs => d3.sum(vs)),
  d => d.color
);

var output = rolled_up.map(([color, values]) => ({ key: color, values: values }));

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```

This:

- Uses [`d3.rollups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#rollups) to group by color and reduce the resulting grouped values:

  - The 3rd parameter is the dimension on which to group items.
  - The 2nd parameter (`vs => d3.transpose(vs.map(d => d.values)).map(vs => d3.sum(vs))`) is the reducing function, transforming grouped values.
- The reducing function makes use of [`d3.transpose`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#transpose) to zip the grouped arrays, before summing each part of the resulting merged array
- Maps elements produced by the rollup to the expected output format.

Here is the intermediate result produced by `d3.rollups`:

```js
var input = [
  { type: "apple", color: "green", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  { type: "apple", color: "red",   values: [5, 6, 7, 8] },
  { type: "grape", color: "green", values: [9, 10, 11, 12] },
  { type: "grape", color: "red",   values: [13, 14, 15, 16] }
];

var rolled_up = d3.rollups(
  input,
  vs => d3.transpose(vs.map(d => d.values)).map(vs => d3.sum(vs)),
  d => d.color
);

console.log(rolled_up);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```