# Summing arrays in JavaScript using d3.nest() Part II

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379912/javascript-summing-arrays-using-d3-nest) about summing arrays in JavaScript using d3.nest()

I got a good solution (two in fact), but it turns out both have an issue when adapted to append additional information:

```
data = [
  {
    continent: 'africa',
    country: 'gabon',
    values: [1, 2]
  }, {
    continent: 'africa',
    country: 'chad',
    values: [3, 4]
  }, {
    continent: 'asia',
    country: 'china',
    values: [1, 2]
  }
];

sum_by = 'continent';

rollupAgg = function(data, sum_by) {
  return d3.nest().key(function(d) {
    return d[sum_by];
  }).rollup(function(group) {
    return group.reduce(function(prev, cur, index, arr) {
      return {
        values: prev.values.map(function(d, i) {
          return d + cur.values[i];
        }),
        sum_by: sum_by       // additional information
      };
    });
  }).entries(data);
};
```

reduce() doesn't run if there is only one row in that group, so this returns the following:

```
[
  {
    "key": "africa",
    "values": {
      "values": [4, 6],
      "sum_by": "continent"
    }
  }, {
    "key": "asia",
    "values": {
      "continent": "asia",
      "country": "china",   // country information shouldn't have been retained
      "values": [1, 2]
    }                       // sum_by information should have been added
  }
];
```

Can you see a way to modify this function so that it returns the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasn't occurred to me till now that a single element array will not execute the function; but it makes sense, because you're using with a single param:

```
[].reduce(function(prev, curr, i, arr) {});// <-- function is the only param
```

When used with a single param, the behavior is that the first time the function is executed, `i` equals 1 (not 0), and `prev` and `curr` are the first and second elements of the array. Since you only have one element, there's no way to call it in this form.

If you use reduce with a 2nd param:

```
[].reduce(function(prev, curr, i, arr) {}, { foo:'bar' });// <-- 2nd param {foo:bar}
```

it does actually call the function, with the first call passing `i` equal to 0 and `prev` equaling `{ foo:'bar' }`.

So I guess you have 2 options:

1. Either modify it to pass a 2nd param, which in your case would need to be `{ values:[0,0] }` (and that hardcodes the fact that `values` is always 2 elements, which will cause an issue if it's longer).
2. Check if `group.length == 1` and if so, `return group`, instead of calling reduce.